# Yup computed validation on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

```
address: Yup.object()
.shape({
address1:Yup.string().required("Please enter valid address1"),
address2:Yup.string().required("Please enter valid address2"),
address3:Yup.string().required("Please enter valid address3"),
})
```

I want an additional validation on all of these fields, whenever combine length of all of these address cross 50 length I need  to show error in all of these fields

Even if address1+address2>50, still show error in all of these fields

Comment: You can add a `.test()` on the object():
`yup.object().shape(...).test('length-test', 'The length must be <50', (value) => { return address1.lenght + address2.length + address3.length < 50 }`
Obv this is a super simplified version, more info on test here: https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema

Comment: But ".test()" will show error only when and action will be done that field, what I want even if user writes more than 50 characters in one of fields all fields should throw error
Can I achieve it via .test() ?